# Planning air travel between Paraguay and Colombia

Tags: air-travel, colombia, paraguay

I am traveling to Paraguay and Colombia this October (order and exact dates are still flexible at this time).

Being a resident of the United States, I am accostomed to US-centric travel (i.e., flying to/from the US).  However, I have very little experience planning travel that is 100% outside the US.

What resources can I use to compare and book flights between Colombia (most likely Bogotá or Medellin) and Paraguay (Asunción)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[despegar.com](http://www.despegar.com/)** is a flight search engine for Latin America that seems pretty good.  (I found out about it recently when someone here on Travel SE mentioned it.)

You should be able to buy the tickets directly through despegar, but I have no experience of how well that works. Alternatively, just use it to find airlines / schedules / prices, and then book via the airline.

(The site is apparently only available in Spanish and Portuguese though.)

---

I had a quick look at flight options between Colombia & Paraguay, and they seem quite poor: apparently there aren't any *direct* flights, and it isn't cheap. Prices of return tickets (incl all taxes and fares):

- Bogotá-Asunción from USD 774. Travel time from 8h 30m (via Lima).
- Medellín-Asunción from USD 764 Travel time from 8h 10m (via Lima).

I got similar results (quite expensive & slow, with no direct flights) from other search engines like [eDreams](http://www.edreams.com/flights/bogota-asuncion/). So it seems Colombia-Paraguay just isn't the most convenient route to fly.

I was wondering why, and well, turns out that Asunción's [Silvio Pettirossi International Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvio_Pettirossi_International_Airport) (ASU)—Paraguay's main international gateway—isn't exactly a major hub. You can only fly to **eight** international destinations from there (Buenos Aires, Miami, Panama City, São Paulo, Lima, Rio de Janeiro, Santa Cruz de la Sierra and Santiago de Chile).

Comment: Also, I noticed this (hopefully transient) oddity about the site. On the front page if you choose the US or maybe Colombia as your country, it won't find any flights at all! Choose **Argentina** and it works.

Comment: Weird; I also noticed that I get different results when I pick a different home country, although interestingly, I actually got more options when I picked US as the home country vs. Argentina.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite site for starting to compare flights, all flights, is still hipmunk.com.

Air travel within Latin America is, sadly, overpriced and underserviced. You're not likely to find a good deal on a flight to Paraguay, from anywhere, which is not a popular destination on the continent.

I'm not sure what the current visa situation is for Americans flying to Brazil, but if it's acceptable, you could consider including Foz de Iguacu in your searches.